# How to make my select menu in iOS devices to display uniform with other inputs?

Tags: css, ios, iphone, select, menu

I have a styles issue that only happens on iOS devices. I've confirmed  in ***Chrome*** +
***Safari*** in iPhone 12 Pro Max.

I can see my local set up code live on my iPhone when I go to the IP Address

Ex.
http://192.168.116.161/mybabies/public/baby/797b808a-e8c6-4a83-acf4-667hhjg?code=8888

[image]

In the ***Chrome*** simulator (as iPhone), it displays perfectly fine.

[image]

How do I make my select menus look uniform with my other inputs?

---

## Update

```
public function settingsUpdate($id){
    $baby     = Baby::where('uuid',$id)->first();   
    if($baby){

        $baby->name            = Request::get('name','');
        $baby->phone           = Request::get('phone','');
        $baby->email           = Request::get('email','');
        $baby->babyName        = Request::get('babyName','');
        $baby->babyDob         = Request::get('babyDob','').' '.Request::get('babyHob','').':00';
        $baby->adminCode       = Request::get('adminCode','');
        $baby->readOnlyCode    = Request::get('readOnlyCode','');
        $baby->feedingInterval = (float) Request::get('feedingInterval',''); <<<----------  ✨
        $baby->feedingAmount   = (float) Request::get('feedingAmount',''); <<<----------  ✨
        $baby->displayMode     = Request::get('displayMode','');

        $baby->save();

        return Redirect::to('/baby/'.$baby->uuid.'?code='.$baby->adminCode);

    } else {
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
}
```

---

## HTML/View

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <label for="feedingInterval"><h5>Feeding Interval <small class="helpText">(hours)</small></h5></label>

        <select class="form-control" id="feedingInterval" name="feedingInterval">
            <option value="2">2 hrs </option>
            <option value="2.5">2.5 hrs </option>
            <option value="3">3 hrs </option>
            <option value="3.5">3.5 hrs </option>
            <option value="4">4 hrs </option>
            <option value="4.5">4.5 hrs </option>
            <option value="5">5 hrs </option>
            <option value="5.5">5.5 hrs </option>
            <option value="6">6 hrs </option>
        </select>

    </div>


    <div class="col-xs-6">
        <label for="feedingAmount"><h5>Feeding Amount <small class="helpText">(ounces)</small></h5></label>

        <select class="form-control" id="feedingAmount" name="feedingAmount">
            <option value="2">2 oz </option>
            <option value="2.5">2.5 oz </option>
            <option value="3">3 oz </option>
            <option value="3.5">3.5 oz </option>
            <option value="4">4 oz </option>
            <option value="4.5">4.5 oz </option>
            <option value="5">5 oz </option>
            <option value="5.5">5.5 oz </option>
            <option value="6">6 oz </option>
        </select>
        
    </div>



</div>
```

---

## GET & SET

```
    $('#feedingInterval').val(`{{$baby->feedingInterval}}`.toString());
    $('#feedingAmount').val(`{{$baby->feedingAmount}}`.toString());
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML and CSS code you are using?

Comment: @SantiagoTorrabadella Let me know, if you need more things ...

Comment: Have you tried Normalize CSS?

Answer (score 1):

`select` elements in *Safari* have their own styling, if you have a custom style in mind, the best thing is using `-webkit-appearance: none;` and define yours.